# How to handle PHP form data both in php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a php file with a form in it that points back to iteself. So in order to proccess the form data with php I have to check if a post variable exists with

```
if(isset($_POST['variable'])).
```

The problem with this is that I want to handle the form data with jquery ajax as well. But jquery doesn't get the post variables that I set inside this if. When i try to leave the if out I get a notice of undefined index. Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Provide the code in question. It sounds like you might have a fundamental issue with understanding the functionality of jquery. You EITHER submit via ajax or not, not both.

Comment: If you want jQuery to handle the variables, then drop the php function `if(isset($_POST['varibale']));` out of the picture and naturally let $.ajax do its work.  Otherwise, script will be at "deadlock" as confused which you want to process the data via php or ajax and will not produce the result.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem and i think that the solution was that I had event.preventdefaul at the start of the jquery function instead of the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an additional `else` statement with will handle AJAX requests, like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['variable'])) {

} else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  // handle AJAX requests
  // the code inside the else if statement is one of the common ways to check
  // whether the request is an AJAX request, but there are also other ways
}
```

The jQuery AJAX part probably does not need to be changed.